# endless rewrite to subfolder apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp

I'm trying to get my /website/ folder to rewrite to `/website/public/` folder
I tried several ways and right now I'm using

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^C:/Users/Compaq/code/website/public/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/website/public/$1 [L]
```

which makes it loop on itself for some reason, doesn't the SCRIPT_FILENAME variable contain "public" the moment the first rewrite happens ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/website/public/$1 [L]
```

Note that this will externally redirect the browser and change the URL location bar. To internally rewrite, you need to remove the `http://localhost` from the rule's target.

Comment: I tried that but I just get "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete." if I add the [R] flag it works but then it becomes a redirection rather than a rewrite and the URL gets changed.

Comment: Yes I'm using RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/public/$1 [L]

Comment: @user3059655 and you don't have any other rules?

Comment: no, the file is completely empty except for the rules you gave me

Comment: there is no problem with the cache, considering I'm not doing a permanent 301 redirection and when i change my rewrite code on several instances, it immediately shows a different result.

Comment: @user3059655 there's nothing in those rules that redirect the browser, without `http://localhost/` and with the `RewriteCond` preventing internal recursion.